# getting the the data from database fill in to the comobbox based on names?

Tags: c#, database

When getting the data from the database fill-in to the combo box based on names…

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CENTAUR09-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select cust_name from customer", con);
con.Open();
comboBox1.DataSource = cmd;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = cmd.ToString();
con.Close();
```

… what are the data source and display members?

Comment: This is just wrong, you are setting the datasource to the SqlCommand item. The query is never being executed so how are you expecting to get results?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CENTAUR09-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true"))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id, cust_name from customer", con); 

       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       adapter.Fill(dt);

       comboBox1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; 
       comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cust_name"; 
       comboBox1.ValueMember = "id"; 
    }
```

**EDIT:**

It is good practice to select either the PK of customer and set its path as VlaueMember